# I want to expand the length of title textbox in report builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I want to horizontally expand the length of the title textbox in Report Builder 3.0 with the expansion of the column.

I think it requires an expression on the textbox but I am not able to enter a proper expression.

"The title textbox must be expand with the expansion of the column 'NAME'."

[image: Design view]

[image: Output View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the textbox to expand with the column group, it has to be within an object that is forced to expand with it. There's no property to simply link their right border.

One option is to add another row outside and above the column group like this:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, you cannot merge these two cells in the top row, but the second cell will grow to cover all the columns in the group.

The other option is to wrap the title and table in another table. To do this you would start by creating a table with 1 column and 2 rows.

[image]

Then you drag the title textbox into the top row and the table into the second row.

[image]

The only downside with this method is that it can be tricky to resize columns, but you can always edit your main table first and then drag it into the other table at the end.